# Создание модели приложения Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте!
Чуть-чуть пытаюсь изучать Ruby on Rails, есть вот такое задание:
[image: Задание]

Собственно, проблема вот в чём: даже примерно не понимаю, как создать такую модель (и что это за модель?). Получается, что первый класс - Project, в нём ссылка на второй класс - Todo?
Хотелось бы получить помощь, потому как гугл выдает только либо более лёгкие примеры, либо гораздо сложнее. Спасибо

Comment: "Получается, что первый класс - Project, в нём ссылка на второй класс - Todo?" По направлению стрелок похоже, хотя здравому смыслу и кардинальности (что к чему и в каком количестве) это прямо противоречит. Стоит уточнить у составителя.

Comment: Окей, а как вообще можно составить такую модель?

Comment: В задании сказано же, генератором. Видимо, `rails g model Название поле:тип поле2:тип`.

Answer (score 2):

Проект имеет множество задач - **has_many**, каждая задача принадлежит проекту **belongs_to**

Генерация моделей

```
rails g model Project title:string
# project:references - создает отношение таблиц в терминах миграции
rails g model Todo text:string isCompleted:boolean project:references
```

Или сразу scaffold (чтобы создать контроллеры, модели и т.д.)

```
rails g scaffold Project title:string
rails g scaffold Todo text:string isCompleted:boolean project:references
```

После создания и перед миграцией можно добавить необходимые параметры в миграцию,
например значения по умолчанию для полей.

После выполнить миграцию (обновить схему базы данных)

```
rails db:migrate
```

В классах моделей (app/models/*)

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Теперь можно использовать

```
@project = Project.create({title: 'Project 1'})
@project.todos.create({text: 'todo 1', isCompleted: false})
@todos = @project.todos.all
```