# Модели и классы в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Собственно вопрос.

Необходимо создать одну модель, у которой будет два класса.
Если взглянуть на изображение - то модель это Project а классы Title и Todos? Или я что то не понимаю... 
   Вводит в ступор  фраза создание модели а не моделей. 
[Тот же вопрос на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772663/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-ruby-on-rails)Тут вообще сказано про создание двух моделей "Проект" и "Тодо".
Помогите разобраться с вопросом.

[image]

Comment: А чем вас не устроил ответ по вашей ссылке? Там же всё расписано дословно буквально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем задание по ссылке из вашего предыдущего вопроса:

> Создаем модель приложения (используя генератор). Модель должна состоять из двух классов. Структура на схеме ниже

Модель - это модель приложения. Этот термин в данном случае не имеет никакого отношения к модели из концепции MVC. Другими словами "смоделируем приложение для создания тудушек, потренируемся на котиках, сделаем упрощенный пример настоящего большого приложения".

Answer (score 0):

Маловато вводных данных, но следуя примитивной логике, то тут будет 2 модели `TODO` с полем `text` и контроллером `isCompleted`, и `Project` c контроллером `TODOs` и полем `Title`.
Далее смотрите по контексту задачи..:)

Comment: Доброй ночи!
Во 2м вопросе сказаны про команды, которые нужно применить в rails concole. Они меня в очередной раз озадачили т.к похоже, что Project и Todo -  модели. При этом тодо принадлежит проекту.                                                                                                                                         
project = Project.create title: "Мой проект"
todo = Todo.create text: "Обсудить проект с женой"
project.todos << todo

Comment: По этому и сказано выше, что вводных данных мало было) Тогда выходит, что у вас будет 2 модели: Project с полем title и контроллером todos, и Todo с полем text и контроллером isCompleted